# Difference between "free now" and "now free"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, adverb-placement

What is the difference between "free now" and "now free" ?

For example-

- "It is free now"
- "It is now free"

What is the differences between these two sentences verbally ?

Some say, "now free" is used for long period and "free now" is used for limited period.

Some say
"now free" for exclamatory or surprised sentences and in other hand "free now" is use in normal present condition.

Comment: IMO, it's just a matter of style. There isn't much difference.

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much interchangeable:

> The rusted bolt was frozen, so I spritzed it with some solvent. It's
>   now free.
>
> The rusted bolt was frozen, so I spritzed it with some solvent. It's
>   free now.

**now** can move around:

> Fido is living on a big farm.
>   He's free **now** to roam wherever he wants.
>   He's **now** free to roam wherever he wants.
>   **Now** he's free to roam wherever he wants.
>   He's free to roam wherever he wants **now**.
>   He's free to roam **now** wherever he wants.

Comment: I disagree to this. 'free now' and 'now free' mean different things. Please check my answer.

Comment: @Holyprogrammer and I disagree with your disagreement. Upvoting, so the question will not be bumped next month by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Like the OP said,

> It is now free

means that 'It' is now free and will be from now on for a long time.

> E.g. [Google Earth Pro is **now** free](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-earth-pro-paid-subscription-service-now-free-656447)

On the other hand,

> Is is free now

Is like saying that it is free for a limited period of time.

> E.g. Monument Valley is free now - app of the day

P.S. I wish monument valley was free...

Comment: **Both** "*Google Earth Pro **is free now***" and "*Google Earth Pro **is now free***"  mean customers/users no longer pay for the service. The answer has not provided any substantiated evidence to prove it otherwise.